# Try to add 1 to a variable and print it, but it outputs the same number

Tags: python

```
    def checked(input, correct):
if input == correct:
    return True
else:
    return False

while True:
    try:
        user_typed = str(raw_input('Type password\n'))
        password = str('test')
        number_of_trys = 0
    if checked(user_typed, password) is True and number_of_trys <= 3:
        print('Welcome User')
        break
    else:
        print("Password is incorrect, please try again.")
        number_of_trys += 1
        print(number_of_trys)
finally:
    print('Loop Complete')
```

I try to print "number_of_trys" but it keeps outputting '1'. And yes, I have tried doing number_of_trys = number_of_trys + 1.

Comment: `number_of_trys = 0` was reseted your variable every while loop. Move it to outside of while

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: The `def checked` being indented more than the material following it looks very wrong to me. Would you fix this in your question if it is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Every time you're asking for the password in try:, you're setting number_of_trys to 0. Declare it outside of the while loop and reset it in the if statement

```
def checked(input, correct):
    if input == correct:
        return True
    else:
        return False

number_of_trys = 0

while True:
    try:
        user_typed = str(raw_input('Type password\n'))
        password = str('test')
    if checked(user_typed, password) is True and number_of_trys <= 3:
        print('Welcome User')
        number_of_trys = 0
        break
    else:
        print("Password is incorrect, please try again.")
        number_of_trys += 1
        print(number_of_trys)
finally:
    print('Loop Complete')
```